# @SpringBootTest loads application context and runs indefinitely without running test case code

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to develop library and write integration tests using `@SpringBootTest`.
I'm supplying custom `@SpringBootApplication` class and when i trigger tests, testcase will start running, spring context loads(banner, hibernete logs) and stucks forever. it doesn't come back to test case code to run it. I've enabled debug logs but nothing useful found. not sure where it's going wrong

Comment: Please add some code/configuration. There is far too little information in your question.